# Show that function is integrable

Tags: complex-analysis

I try to prove that $f(z)= \int_0^{+\infty}e^{zt}t^{-t}  dt $ is holomorphic.

What I did:
Let $\Gamma $ be a closed path in $\mathbb{C}$

If we apply Fubini's theorem on the measurable function $(t,z) \rightarrow e^{zt}t^{-t}$  we have $\int_{\Gamma} \int_0^{+\infty}e^{zt}t^{-t} dt = \int_0^{+\infty}  \int_{\Gamma}e^{zt}t^{-t} dt $.

However, $\mathbb{C} $ is convex and $z \rightarrow e^{zt}t^{-t}$  is holomorphic so after Cauchy's theorem  $\int_{\Gamma}e^{zt}t^{-t} dt=0$

We deduce that $\int_{\Gamma} f(z) dz = 0 $, then with Morera's theorem, we show that f is holomorphic.

But how to ensure that $(t,z) \rightarrow e^{zt}t^{-t}$ is integrable to use Fubini's theorem  properly?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is improper only at $\infty$, since
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}e^{tz}t^{-t}=1.
$$
Moreover, it is uniformly convergent on compact subsets of $\Bbb C$. If $|z|\le R$  and $t\ge2$
$$
\bigl|\,e^{tz}t^{-t}\,\bigr|\le\Bigl(\frac{e^R}{t}\Bigr)^t\le\frac{e^{2R}}{t^2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! could you please point me to a theorem or a reference? I still don't get the notion of " uniformly convergent on compact subsets". I thought uniform convergence was related to function sequences ?

Comment: In terms of Lebesgue measure, there is an integrable bound independent of $z$. In terms of improper Riemann integral, you can read about it in classical analysis books, like Apostol's.